# Does the dimension of a submanifold never exceed that of its ambient manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Before we start, let me recap a few definitions from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

> Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary. An ***embedded submanifold of $M$*** is a subset $S\subseteq M$ that is manifold (without boundary) in the subspace topology, endowed with a smooth structure with respect to which the incluion map $S\hookrightarrow M$ is a smooth embedding. Embedded submanifolds are also called ***regular submanifolds*** by some authors. If $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$, the difference $\dim M-\dim S$ is called the ***codimension of $S$ in $M$***, and the containing manifold $M$ is called the ***ambient manifold for $S$***.

A question has been in my mind for a long time: why do we define the codimension of $S$ in $M$ to be $\dim M-\dim S$? **Is this an implication that $\dim S\leq\dim M$?** I tried to draw this conclusion based on what I have learned, but in vain. Here's my thought:

Since the inclusion map $\iota:S\hookrightarrow M$ is a smooth embedding, we know $\iota$ is not only a smooth immersion but also a topological embedding. By a topological embedding, we mean $S$ is homeomorphic to $\iota(S)=S$, which seems to add nothing. Let's talk about the smooth immersion. It's a smooth map whose differential is injective everywhere. That tells us $\mathrm{rank}(\iota)=\dim S$, from which I can't go anywhere. Is it possible to relate $\mathrm{rank}(\iota)$ to $\dim M$? Or, is my guess about $\dim S\leq\dim M$ totally an illusion?
Thank you.

Comment: If it helps: The same inequality is true for vector subspaces of a real vector space, which are the local model for submanifolds.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Gosh, I didn't expect to use that! Indeed, for each $p\in S$, $T_p S$ can be characterized as a subspace of $T_p M$. Thank you, Andrew.

Comment: Also, for every point $p \in S \subseteq M$, there exists local coordinates $ U \times V$ for $M$, such that $U$ is local coordinate for $S$. And dim $U \leq$ dim $ U \times V$. I know this is an overkill, but still wanted to share. :)